# How to display only lines 12-24 of an arbitrary text file?

Tags: bash

I have a set of text files and I'd like to display lines 12-14 by running a bash script on each file.

For one of the files, this works:

```
tail -14 | head -11
```

But since other files have different lengths, I cannot run the same script on them.

What is the command I'm looking for to output lines 12-24 of the text file?

Comment: `head -24|tail -12`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sed` with `-n` argument

```
sed -n 12,24p <FILENAME>
```

Comment: accepting answers is preferable than leaving such kind of messages

Answer (score 1):

For a funny pure Bash (≥4) possibility:

```
mapfile -t -s 11 -n 13 lines < file
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}"
```

This will skip the first 11 lines (with `-s 11`) and read 13 lines (with `-n 13`) and store each line in a field of the array `lines`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '12<= NR && NR <= 24' file
```

In `awk`, `NR` is the line number.  The above condition insists that `NR` be both greater than or equal to 12 and less than or equal to 24.  If it is, then the line is printed.  Otherwise, it isn't.

#### A more efficient solution

It would be more efficient to stop reading the file after the upper line limit has been reached.  This solution does that:

```
awk 'NR>24 {exit;} NR>=12' file
```